# How to get line WITH tab character using tail and head

Tags: bash

I have made a script to practice my Bash, only to realize that this script does not take tabulation into account, which is a problem since it is designed to find and replace a pattern in a Python script (which obviously needs tabulation to work).

Here is my code. Is there a simple way to get around this problem ?

```
pressure=1
nline=$(cat /myfile.py | wc -l) # find the line length of the file
echo $nline
for ((c=0;c<=${nline};c++)) 
do
    res=$( tail -n $(($(($nline+1))-$c)) myfile.py | head -n 1 | awk 'gsub("="," ",$1){print $1}' | awk '{print$1}') 
    #echo $res
    if [ $res == 'pressure_run' ]
    then 
        echo "pressure_run='${pressure}'" >> myfile_mod.py
    else 
        echo $( tail -n $(($nline-$c)) myfile.py | head -n 1) >> myfile_mod.py
    fi
done
```

Basically, it finds the line that has `pressure_run=something` and replaces it by `pressure_run=$pressure`. The rest of the file should be untouched. But in this case, all tabulation is deleted.

Comment: `sed "s/pressure_run=something/pressure_run=$pressure/" file > outFile && mv outFile file` ?? Good luck.

Comment: Do you want to insert literally `$pressure`, or literally `${pressure}`, or actually the value of the `$pressure` variable (`1`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to just do the replacement as quickly as possible, sed is the way to go as pointed out in [shellter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/620097/shellter)'s comment:

```
sed "s/\(pressure_run=\).*/\1$pressure/" myfile.py
```

For Bash training, as you say, you may want to loop manually over your file. A few remarks for your current version:

- Is `/myfile.py` really in the root directory? Later, you don't refer to it at that location.
- `cat ... | wc -l` is a [useless use of `cat`](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html) and better written as `wc -l < myfile.py`.
- Your `for` loop is executed one more time than you have lines.
- To get the next line, you do "show me all lines, but counting from the back, don't show me `c` lines, and then show me the first line of these". There *must* be a simpler way, right?
- To get what's the left-hand side of an assignment, you say "in the first space-separated field, replace `=` with a space , then show my the first space separated field of the result". There *must* be a simpler way, right? This is, by the way, where you strip out the leading tabs (your first awk command does it).
- To print the unchanged line, you do the same complicated thing as before.

#### A band-aid solution

A minimal change that would get you the result you want would be to modify the awk command: instead of

```
awk 'gsub("="," ",$1){print $1}' | awk '{print$1}'
```

you could use

```
awk -F '=' '{ print $1 }'
```

"Fields are separated by `=`; give me the first one". This preserves leading tabs.

The replacements have to be adjusted a little bit as well; you now want to match something that *ends* in `pressure_run`:

```
if [[ $res == *pressure_run ]]
```

I've used the more flexible `[[ ]]` instead of `[ ]` and added a `*` to `pressure_run` (which must *not* be quoted): "if `$res` ends in `pressure_run`, then..."

The replacement has to use `$res`, which has the proper amount of tabs:

```
echo "$res='${pressure}'" >> myfile_mod.py
```

Instead of appending each line each loop (and opening the file each time), you could just redirect output of your whole loop with `done > myfile_mod.py`.

This prints literally `${pressure}` as in your version, because it's single quoted. If you want to replace that by the value of `$pressure`, you have to remove the single quotes (and the braces aren't needed here, but don't hurt):

```
echo "$res=$pressure" >> myfile_mod.py
```

This fixes your example, but it should be pointed out that enumerating lines and then getting one at a time with `tail | head` is a really bad idea. You traverse the file for every single line twice, it's very error prone and hard to read. <sub>(Thanks to [tripleee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee) for suggesting to mention this more clearly.)</sub>

#### A proper solution

This all being said, there are preferred ways of doing what you did. You essentially loop over a file, and if a line matches `pressure_run=`, you want to replace what's on the right-hand side with `$pressure` (or the value of that variable). Here is how I would do it:

```
#!/bin/bash

pressure=1

# Regular expression to match lines we want to change
re='^[[:space:]]*pressure_run='

# Read lines from myfile.py
while IFS= read -r line; do

    # If the line matches the regular expression
    if [[ $line =~ $re ]]; then

        # Print what we matched (with whitespace!), then the value of $pressure
        line="${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"$pressure
    fi

    # Print the (potentially modified) line
    echo "$line"

# Read from myfile.py, write to myfile_mod.py
done < myfile.py > myfile_mod.py
```

For a test file that looks like

```
blah
   test

pressure_run=no_tab
    blah

something
    pressure_run=one_tab
        pressure_run=two_tabs
```

the result is

```
blah
   test

pressure_run=1
    blah

something
    pressure_run=1
        pressure_run=1
```

#### Recommended reading

- [How to read a file line-by-line](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) (explains the `IFS=` and `-r` business, which is quite essential to preserve whitespace)
- [BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide)

Comment: The `cat foo | wc -l` is better written `wc -l <foo` with the same effect. Using `=` in `[[` does not seem to have any portability benefits, as `[[` is not portable anyway. Maybe specifically point out that enumerating line numbers so you can read one line at a time with `head | tail` is a monumental antipattern of its own.  But +1!

Comment: @tripleee Thanks for the feedback on the feedback! Updated. I *knew* there must be a way to get rid of that UUOC ;)

Comment: That's great ! Thanks for the detailed answer, did not expect such a complete answer !